# Increase body fat before multi day endurance event?

Tags: running, training, nutrition, calories, body-fat

Does anyone know of any research / literature on increasing body fat before multi day endurance events?

Specifically, 1. cycling high on fats and carbs for a month or two then 2. dropping into a targeted calorie range at daily expenditure for a week or two before the event 3. running a potentially unpreventable calorie deficit during the event